# How do I remove kernel boot entries in refind?

Tags: 14.04, macbook-pro, refind

I have the latest 13 inch macbook pro retina with 256gb solid state drive, I have triple booted OSX, Ubuntu and Windows.  Every time I updated Ubuntu to a newer kernel it adds a new boot option in refind how do I stop this and only show latest version of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Edit your rEFInd.conf file. Search for the following line, uncomment by removing the "#" and ensure it is set to "true".

```
fold_linux_kernels true
```